# Точечная линия. XML

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, background

Доброго времени суток.
Такой вопрос: как сделать точечную линию, да так, что бы была линия с точек, которые круглые, а не прямоугльники.
Есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это код XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:color="#C7B299"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                android:dashGap="5px"
                android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="0px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

А нужно такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://baiduhix.blogspot.ru/2015/06/android-dot-line.html